# Magento 2 - Multi Flat shipping not showing frontend checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, checkout-page, table-rates, flat

I am using Meetanshi Flatshipping extension. I have added flat rate in admin based on country but flat shipping is not showing on checkout page.I have 5 shipping methods for UK, only 4 are showing on checkout. I also add flat rate for Canada but not showing.

I have also used another Flat shipping extension but facing same issue.

Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to enter the zip code then after shipping method will display

Comment: Where to add zip code?

Comment: in the shipping address, there is the field called "Zip/Postal Code"

Comment: I have already test zip code. I have 6 shipping flat rate for UK. Just 4 are showing on check out page. Couldn't  figure out what is the issue.

Comment: I have to see the admin panel for that I event not able to figure it out without looking at your configuration.

Comment: I have done this using matrix rate.Thanks for you help.